# How to automatically create a TypeScript interface from a TypeScript class?

Tags: typescript

In a library I frequently have class expressions to create local (nested) classes. However, such local classes may not contain private or protected members (because I enabled `declaration` in tsconfig.json). Hence I have to make all members (even inherited ones) public, like in this example:

```
class A {
    protected do() {
        console.log("do");
    }
}

interface B extends A {
    do(): void
}

class B extends A {}

class C {
    public static readonly D = class D extends B {

    }
}

const d = new C.D();
d.do();
```

The code uses declaration merging (class B and interface B) to accomplish the task. To play with the code use this [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=8&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQA4CcD2AXApsAQCbTHYAUAlIimvcNgHYTYj4B0I2A5hQETl%20VANx1UAXyRSkASyYFMAMzDB80AELR8ADwJNiMeMnrlqALmgA3bLOLSkSUJBhbd%20w3EQznUaAGFaenQAVwAjEFlgaAhcMFwo6Ex8MHImEABPaAARaABeaF8YXPd8A1dacWgpH2ZYsnzoJnwAdwCObOoxYg4zUSA). To see an error about required accessibility replace B with A in the extends clause in the class expression.

This works pretty well, but has a big drawback: the manual work required to collect all members and create an interface for them.

So I wonder if there's a way in TypeScript to generate an interface out of all members in a class. Similar to the utility types like `Partial<T>`.

I know I can use a side namespace and move the local class to that (which also uses declaration merging), but that doesn't solve the problem at hand. What if I have a class factory method? This cannot be moved out (since it needs the outer class), but has the same problem as the class expression.

Comment: you've lost the point of the role of Interfaces in OOP. That language construct has a well defined purpose, to help in the design of abstractions to decouple object relationships in an application. I think you need work with DTO' pattern, unless you're wanting to build shit software

Comment: Are you aware that if `Foo` is a class, then you can *also* use `Foo` like it's an interface? You can write `class Bar implements Foo { ... }` and it works just fine.

Comment: A class can be used as an interface as well. It's the reason why `interface B extends A` works. I don't understand the problem statement here.

Comment: all sort of this weird things and behavior TS allows us to make is because TS is a tool that help us to make mistakes that could be caught in dev/build time. It doesnt will make any diff in runtime where all of these constrainst are not enforced anymore.

Comment: Take for example a good practice in software development called: Interface segregation, which is very recommended to be followed, and all benefits are known. An interface is a contract in OOP, a class that signs to a contract must follow and implement what it must implement. A class can have more methods than the contract  that an interface enforces, and this is good because promotes writing short methods, separation of concerns,  DRY (dont repeat yourself), allowing sharing of code, testability, easy manteinance, etc. So I'll just never write a code that is a interface extending a class.

Comment: anyway, I recommend you to create a vscode plugin or a script that automates code generation for solving your issue cause in terms of semantic, you are for some reason only you know making use of interfaces duplicating class dclarations in a freestylew way. My point is to give you a hint to think wha you are planning to do. Its wrong. It smells. And in the future you will laugh a lot, out loud when read this again. I remember nmy junior days when I exceed the reflection case uses in C#, genereating classes at runtime etc. and all sorts of hacking language. I've stopped

Comment: @apokryfos The point with the interface is that it makes all the members listed in it public. That's the only reason it exists. Otherwise I would have to implement all non-public members again with public accessibility (what I do not want). There's no way in TS to raise the accessibility level like in other languages.

Comment: @JonePolvora I think you went a bit too far with your comments. See where I come from with this problem: nested classes and enabled declaration for TS builds. This requires that all members of the nested type must be public (why doesn't matter here). But local classes can inherit many non-public members from their inheritance chain, which would cause a lot of work.

Comment: the original concept behind interfaces was provide kind of contracts to be respected, which adds a certain level of prediction on how they interacts and behave, enabling new ways of thinking in solving problems. Interface definitions should follow the segregation principle, being small and objective. Enforcing classes to implement only necessary behavior. You are overengineering and overcomplicating code, throwing away semantic that OOP provides, in an obsessive way to solve a problem you think exists but then you will concluse that is your own design flaw.

Comment: Stop using TypeScript accessibility modifiers.